# What is the JSON format for a firestore individual field index within a collection group query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

We can now retrieve documents from a collection group which is great. To do so, I need to create an index through an error message on the Firebase console. How can I add this new index to the firestore.indexes.json file?

Example of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

```
let museums = db.collectionGroup('landmarks').where('type', '==', 'museum');
museums.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
});
```

Comment: if you add added through the firebase console, it will auto sync with your project if you are using the cli tool

Comment: interesting @DougStevenson I always asked how come they appeared on my projects then

Comment: That only works when you firebase init for the first time.  After that, there is no sync.

Comment: there you go... there more you know, thank u @DougStevenson

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the top level of your index file, add a new element called `fieldOverrides` and populate it like this:

```
{
  "fieldOverrides": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "landmarks",
      "fieldPath": "type",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "order": "ASCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "order": "DESCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "arrayConfig": "CONTAINS",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "order": "ASCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION_GROUP"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This preserves the all the default automatic indexing for the `type` field in `landmarks` at the `COLLECTION` scope, and allows for `type` also to be used at the `COLLECTION_GROUP` scope.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson!

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please accept it as correct.