# Firestore permutation explosion of composite index

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm stuck in the composite index of firestore. I have a couple of fields under a user, which are like A(string), B(string), C(string), D(array), E(array), F(array), G(array). Users can be searched and queried by different combinations of these fields. For example, "A == 'Male', B == '2020' ", which tells me to create composite index and after I created the query like "A == 'Male', B == '2020', C == "Ontario' " still needs a new composite index.

1. What I'm wondering is that do I have to create all the permutation of composite index?
2. The array fields are more than two, but the SDK only allows one "array-contains" clause. What can I do for this? For this, I have tried to split an array [element1,element2] to the structure like "element1 : true, element2 : true", which can be queried by "==" clause. But the problem is that the array is dynamic, every time I append a "==" clause, the SDK tells me I need to create a new composite index.

Anyone has any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tooling that will create all the desired combinations automatically.  However, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing) suggests that you can use the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) to deploy indexes that are defined using its JSON configuration.  This configuration file is not documented, so you will have to reverse engineer it based on indexes that you create manually.  An example of one such index configuration is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428593/what-is-the-json-format-for-a-firestore-individual-field-index-within-a-collecti).  What you can do is manually create an index, then run `firebase init`, choose Firestore, and it will dump the indexes to its JSON config, which you can edit and redeploy.  As of today, you will have to run `firebase init` in a fresh folder to get new indexes from the server.

Once you know how to deploy indexes like this, you can write code to create all the combinations of indexes in that JSON config.  It's not pretty, but it's doable.

Comment: Thanks and I'll try it. I just updated my question and can you please have a look?

Comment: FYI it's runs against Stack Overflow convention to change the nature of a question, especially after it's already been answered.  It invalidates the answer and could confuse others who might see it.  I suggest reverting the change, and posting your new question as a separate question.